# Spring Test cannot get Spring Configuration Beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        environment.getProperty("bhavya",Boolean.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Profile("test")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.bhavya.test"})
    public static class EnvironmentServiceTestConfiguration{

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Environment environment(){
           return Mockito.mock(Environment.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried putting EnvironmentServiceTestConfiguration as a non-inner non-static class, but didn't help.

Here is what I tried in a separate class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
class EnvironmentServiceTestConfiguration{

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Environment environment(){
        return Mockito.mock(Environment.class)
    }
}
```

didn't work either

The test class is located in test/java/com.bhavya.test package.
I am trying to run this particular test test1

This is my first test of such kind. I have never before used AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, enlighten me.

Stacktrace :

java.lang.NullPointerException

at Line number where I have statement :

```
environment.getProperty("bhavya",Boolean.class);
```

Comment: It is just java.lang.NullPointerException
at Line number where I have statement :

environment.getProperty("bhavya",Boolean.class);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Here is an example explaining how can be done 
https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/

Here is a code sample that works for the sample in the question:

package com.example.demo.test;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("bhavya",Boolean.class));
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.demo.test"})
    public static class EnvironmentServiceTestConfiguration{

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Environment environment(){
            Environment env =  Mockito.mock(Environment.class);
            when(env.getProperty(eq("bhavya"), eq(Boolean.class))).thenReturn(true);

            return env;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me :
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bhavya.test.ConfigurationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<java.lang.Object>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Why does it tries to create a bean for ConfigurationTest ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below annotations for your test class

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```